# Will drinking alcohol kill corona virus inside our body?

Tags: health

In recent days there are so many messages spreading over the social media saying drinking alcohol kills corona virus in our body? Is this true? As far as I understand, using alcohol based hand rubes will kill the virus from the surface of our body and it won't work inside our body.

Comment: No, that rumor is completely wrong. The alcohol based sanitizers need to be 70% to be effective. If you ever got the alcohol concentration up to that level in the body, you would be dead from alcohol poisoning.

Comment: Just as a point of comparison, here in the US you are considered legally drunk at a blood alcohol concentration of just 0.8%.

Comment: Please do not believe such fake scoops, there are other small things we can do to stay safe. In the case you think to be infected, contact a doctor, do not search for advices online. This public panic will be over ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the short answer is: **no**. Alcoholic drinks do not prevent or heal, as stated by the World Health Organization on February 21, 2020, in a post on their Facebook profile ([source](https://www.facebook.com/WHO/photos/a.167668209945237/2932800913431939/)).

[image: image from WHO FB account]

Comment: I guess Corona beer will not help either.

Comment: @KenGraham Yes, 7bridges Imperial IPA would be way better no matter what the emergency is ;) but - now serouusly - you know better than me how to deal with that tag :)